# Creating Object based on Custom Attribute

Tags: c#, attributes, abstract-class

I have a abstract class

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract void CreateGraph(){}
}

[CustomAttribute(Property1 = value , Property2 = value2)]
public class Graph1 : BaseClass
{
 public override void CreateGraph()
     {
       //implementation
     }
}
```

How to Create object of `Graph1`  using `CustomAttribute` property value.
and is it a good approach for Creating object.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not a good approach because in .NET attribute values must be known at compile time. For example `value` and `value2` in your example can only be constant values which is quite limiting the possibilities for setting values.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use attributes for this, just follow common object-oriented design. Check out the [Factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

If you want custom attributes you should define a class inheriting from System.Attribute. Actually you can have several times your custom attribute with different values if you set the AllowMultiple parameter to true in the System.AttributeUsage.

You can [check that here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

However you dont need that to "create object", I'm not sure to see what you mean here by "good approach". As sten mentioned you should have a look at the GoF
 design patterns for best practices, depending what you need to do.